# A question about automorphisms between two isomorphic groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two isomorphic finite groups. Suppose that $\sigma_i:G_i\to G_i$ and $\sigma_i':G_i\to G_i$ be two isomorphisms for $i=1,2$.

When is there an isomorphism $\phi:G_1\to G_2$ such that $\phi\sigma_1=\sigma_2\phi$ and $\phi\sigma_1'=\sigma_2'\phi$?

Thanks for your helps in advance

P.S.

The origin of the problem:

Let $G=G_1\times G_2$ and suppose that $Aut(G)$ denote the automorphism group of $G$. Clearly every $\sigma\in Aut(G)$ such that $\sigma(G_1)=G_1$ and $\sigma(G_2)=G_2$ can induce a group automorphism of $G_1$ and $G_2$.

I try find a bijection $\phi$ from $G_1$ to $G_2$ such that $$\phi(\sigma(g_1))=\sigma(\phi(g_1))$$
for a subgroup $H$ of $Aut(G)$  such that every $\sigma\in H$
has  the above property.

If for every $g_1\in G_1$ we have

$$ \phi(\sigma(\phi^{-1}(g_2)))=\sigma(g_2),$$
then it is a bijection with the above property.

Comment: Take $\sigma_1 = \sigma_1'$ and $\sigma_2, \sigma_2'$ distinct.

Comment: @TastyRomeo Thank you very much for your help but I mean for arbitrary $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma'_i$.

Comment: @TastyRomeo Thanks so much. You mean that it is not always possible. I correct the question.

Comment: You'll get some feeling for how complicated this is by looking at examples. For instance, try $G_1=G_2=\text{GL}(V)$ with $V$ a finite dimensional vector space. Answering the question whether there exists $\phi$ with $\phi^{-1}\sigma_1\phi=\sigma'_1$ is equivalent to the Rational Canonical Form Theorem -- non-trivial but within anyone's grasp. Now asking when we can do this simultaneously for a pair of $\sigma$'s: that's going to need a bit of work.

Comment: ps You said finite groups so $V$ had better be over a finite field.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks so much. You help me very much by your nice examples

Comment: Since $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic, this question is equivalent to taking $G_1 = G_2$, in which case $\sigma_i, \sigma_i', \phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(G_1)$. I don't think this makes the problem any easier to solve, but perhaps it's easier to think about it or come up with examples.

Comment: Thanks guys for your helps and please forgive me if I do not explain the main problem. I added it to the problem.

Comment: @khers This question is beyond me so this may be way off but just based on intuition alone I'm thinking about when $\phi$ and $\sigma$ are involutions, perhaps thinking about this gives you some conditions which are useful?  Furthermore if the group is abelian and $\phi$ is equivalent to $n$ compositions of some function $f$, satisfying $f^q=f$ and $\sigma_p$ is equivalent to $m_p$ compositions of $f$ then you have that when $\phi\times m_1\equiv\phi\times m_2\pmod{q}$ fulfils your rules I think?